# Give table column alias without "( and ")" in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have string representing the select clause of an SQL query, e.g.:

```
val a = "eid,year(join_dt),month(join_dt)"
```

I want to run `select $a from emp`.

I want to give alias for each element from the string like, output sting should be `"eid as eid, year(join_dt) as yearjoin_dt, month(join_dt) as monthjoin_dt"` - how can I perform this string manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's really a robust solution (assumes input is a well-structured comma-separated list of fields, and that field names have only alphanumeric and underscore characters), but this should do it:

```
val a = "eid,year(join_dt),month(join_dt)"

val result = a.split(",")
 .map(s => s"$s as ${s.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z_]", "")}")
 .mkString(", ")

println(result)
// eid as eid, year(join_dt) as yearjoin_dt, month(join_dt) as monthjoin_dt
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer for future readers to know it helped.